# Converting QGIS public transportation route data to GTFS format

Tags: python, routes, qgis

I'm new to using QGIS, working on a public transportation project where I have bus route data collected in QGIS. However, I need to convert this data to the GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification) format in order to use it in various route planning applications and services. I've been searching for tools or methods to perform this conversion, but so far, I haven't found a solution that works for me.

My main goal is to transform geometric data stored in a cell (in WKT format in QGIS) into latitude and longitude points distributed across several rows, without losing the reference to the route they belong to. So far, I've managed to convert the geometry of the route into individual rows of latitude and longitude points. However, I'm unsure if this approach adequately maintains the reference of the route ID.

Is there any other method or tool within QGIS that facilitates this process without losing the reference to the route (or making it more akin to a database)?

I've got the data like this:
[image: Data I have]

This is what I get:
[image: Data I get]